# uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'major' of undefined

Tags: android, react-native, updates

I'm developing an android app with native java & react native. After updating the react native and the dependencies, whenever the development server scripts(locally ) were loaded into the device, it's giving the following error in the typical red screen:

```
com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'major' of undefined

loadApplicationScript
WebSocketJavascriptExecutor.java:173

run
NativeRunnable.java

handleCallback
Handler.java:836
```

My dependencies list : (from package.json)

```
"dependencies": {
"create-react-class": "^15.6.3",
"lodash": "^4.17.5",
"minutes-seconds-milliseconds": "^1.0.3",
"prop-types": "^15.6.1",
"react": "^16.3.0-alpha.2",
"react-native": "^0.54.2",
"react-native-carousel": "^0.11.0",
"react-native-checkbox": "^2.0.0",
"react-native-code-push": "^5.3.1",
"react-native-communications": "^2.2.1",
"react-native-deprecated-custom-components": "^0.1.2",
"react-native-elements": "^0.19.0",
"react-native-masked-text": "^1.6.5",
"react-native-modal-dropdown": "^0.6.2",
"react-native-modal-picker": "0.0.16",
"react-native-parsed-text": "0.0.20",
"react-native-selectbox": "^0.1.2",
"react-native-simple-radio-button": "^2.7.1",
"react-native-tab-view": "0.0.74",
"react-native-tabbed-view-pager-android": "^1.0.4",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^4.5.0",
"react-redux": "^5.0.7",
"react-timer-mixin": "^0.13.3",
"redux": "^3.6.0"},

 "devDependencies": {
"babel-jest": "22.4.1",
"babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
"babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
"jest": "22.4.2",
"react-native-bundle": "0.0.4",
"react-test-renderer": "16.2.0"},
```

In the JS console, it's giving following error :

```
 Cannot read property 'major' of undefined
 Failed to print error:  regeneratorRuntime is not defined
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: Cannot read property 'root' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47663765/typeerror-cannot-read-property-root-of-undefined)

Comment: @krishankTripathi nope. this is different issue.