# Material UI migrating from 3 to 4: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'root' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am migrating from version 3 to 4
I didnt put this on material github page, because couldnt reproduce the error on codesanbox.

Dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "4.1.1",
    "@material-ui/styles": "4.1.1",
    "@material-ui/icons": "4.2.0",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "16.8.6"
  },
```

### Expected Behavior

Component should render.

### Current Behavior

Error says: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'root' of undefined at Button.js

### Steps to Reproduce

Very simple example is here in codesanbox:
This is working, however same code is not working on my local.

Link:
1. https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-4gvz0

I dig into a bit using debugger, on this image, debugger runs line 43, however never runs line 44. Which means that never renders component `WithStyles` and so, in Button props, prop name `classes` comes undefined and.

@material-ui/styles: withStyles.js
[image: @material-ui/styles: withStyles.js]

in Button.js => classes = props.classes
[image]
classes.root => which gives actual error..

Comment: Have you checked out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47663765/typeerror-cannot-read-property-root-of-undefined?

Comment: @NateBosscher yes, it is for old version. And did not help

Comment: I ran into the same problem with my web app, I wonder if it has something to do with the bundling configuration. B/c when I build the same component with create-react-app, it works fine. Just with my custom webpack it doesn't work...